# Normalizing an array to a specific max value using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a function to normalize an array of floats to a given max value using Python 3

I can get it to work in Matlab / Octave but having some difficulty converting that over to Python 3.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**My Matlab / Octave code / function that works:**

```
function normalize=rtnormalize(signal,amp)  
    normalize=(signal/max(abs(signal))*amp);
end

a=[1,2,3,4]
rtnormalize(a,1)
the answer is = 0.25,0.5,0.75,1
```

Another working example:

```
rtnomalize(a,1.45)
the answer is = 0.3625,0.725,1.0875,1.45
```

**However making a similar Python 3 Function below:**

```
import math
import numpy as np

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def rtnormalize(curr_array,max_value_wanted):
    arry_norm = curr_array/np.amax(np.absolute(curr_array))*max_value_wanted

    return arry_norm
print(a)
print(rtnormalize(a,1.45))
```

Gives me:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[0 0 0 1.45]
```

I was expecting

```
the answer to be = 0.3625,0.725,1.0875,1.45
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
**Version: 1.39.0
Commit: 9df03c6d6ce97c6645c5846f6dfa2a6a7d276515
Date: 2019-10-09T06:58:03.188Z
Electron: 4.2.10
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 4.15.0-65-generic snap**
```

See image / animation

[image: bug?]
[image]

Comment: @gboffi Added an image with arrows that says it's python 3.6.8 is this not correct if so how can I fix it?

Comment: what do you see if you just go to the terminal and enter `python`? the line in the VS Code terminal says it's just calling `python`, whatever version is linked there. Also, maybe check [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) resource.

Comment: @MrFuppes I added another animation that shows that it may be a bug. `https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7896`

Now I'm looking for away to work around it

Comment: do you also experience this behaviour if call "debug -> start debugging" `F5` / `CTRL+F5`? I'm on a Windows machine right now but in that case VS Code chooses the *displayed* Python interpreter. If I just call the .py script via the VS Code Terminal as "python script.py", it uses the Python interpreter that is linked to the "python" command

Comment: @MrFuppes running it in debugging the output is correct it uses the `/usr/bin/python3` command so it seems part of the main VS Code configuration isn't using the correct configuration parameter for which python it should execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your IDE tells you notwithstanding, you are using Python 2.7

```
13:40 boffi@debian:~ $ cat test.py
from __future__ import print_function
from numpy import abs, amax
def f(a,mx):
    return a/amax(abs(a))*mx
print(f([1,2,3,4], 1.45))
13:40 boffi@debian:~ $ /usr/bin/python3.7 test.py
[0.3625 0.725  1.0875 1.45  ]
13:40 boffi@debian:~ $ /usr/bin/python2.7 test.py
[0.   0.   0.   1.45]
13:41 boffi@debian:~ $
```

Comment: Thanks it may be a bug...I filed a report with an animated gif showing what it does.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7896

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
import numpy as np

test_array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def rtnormalize(curr_array,max_value_wanted):
    arry_norm = curr_array/np.amax(np.absolute(curr_array))*max_value_wanted

    return arry_norm
print(test_array)
print(rtnormalize(test_array,1.45))
```

I ran your code (the part above) inside PyCharm and it worked perfectly fine, maybe something is wrong with the setup of your environment?

What is math used for here?

Comment: Strange I run it under Visual Studio Code and I don't..
`Version: 1.39.0
Commit: 9df03c6d6ce97c6645c5846f6dfa2a6a7d276515
Date: 2019-10-09T06:58:03.188Z
Electron: 4.2.10
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 4.15.0-65-generic snap`

Comment: Strange I ran it with VS Code (same version) as well and it worked, do you use Anaconda as a interpreter or something else?

Comment: I added an image with arrows along with the version I'm running above